# Can user profile pages please contain rich snippet data?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, semantics

For those of you who haven't heard of rich snippets, it essentially involves inserting special data into HTML markup that describe content on the page. The benefit would be really neat looking search results on Google.

For example (and this is just an example), my Stack Overflow profile might look like:

[image: Search result snippet for the user "George Edison" on Stack Overflow, showing reputation points and location, as well as the usual snippet description]

Pretty neat, eh? So what needs to be done to implement this? Well, according to the [rich snippet documentation](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170), you need to use one of three formats: [microdata](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=176035), [microformats](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146897), or [RDFa](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146898).

Microdata is probably the easiest and looks something like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
  <b>Name:</b>
    <span itemprop="name">George Edison</span><br />
  <b>Homepage:</b>
    <a href="http://www.quickmediasolutions.com" itemprop="url">
    QuickMediaSolutions.com</a>
  <b>Type:</b>
    <span itemprop="title">Regular User</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might be.. imagining.. the way google processes this data. Can you provide a screenshot of a REAL ACTUAL SEARCH RESULT that shows up this way, that is, uses the metadata on the page? Because that would be highly exploitable by evildoers.

Comment: @Jeff: Sure. A Google search for "Cut the Rope Android" displays a rich snippet from the Android Market. The rating and price data are pulled directly from the microdata on the page.

Comment: that is a trusted Google site. Can you provide an example from a site that isn't operated by Google?

Comment: @Jeff: Sure. A Google search for "san francisco concerts yelp" will display a couple of events that were pulled from the hCard data on the page (hCard is one of the supported formats for rich snippet data).

Comment: This blog post suggests that rich snippets were activated automatically some time ago: http://www.webnodes.com/rich-snippets-enabled-automatically so it might be possible to pull this off maybe...

Comment: @ChristopheD: It seems like Stack Apps already includes rich snippet data - it's turning up in custom searches.